# UserControl traer al frente(que tenga el foco)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una app de escritorio(windows forms) en la cual mis ventanas son UserControl los cuales los llamo desde un menu que esta verticalmente al lado izquierdo, al lado derecho tengo un Panel que me sirve como piso en donde llamo a los UserControl, pero me acabo de dar cuenta que cuando tienes un UserControl ya en el Panel y llamas a otro UserControl envez de venir encima del que ya estaba aparece debajo.

¿Hay alguna manera de traer al frente a un UserControl si es que ya hay uno dentro de un Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas cargando User control dentro de un panel seria recomendable descargar el que tenias previamente removiendolo

```
public void mnuxx_Click(..){

   Panel1.Controls.Clear();

   UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
   Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);

}
```

De esta forma no tendrias problemas de superposicion de controles, ademas si solo estas teniendo un control activo para que tener el resto en memoria.

Comment: Mejor regreso a usar formularios y no me complico.

Comment: @PedroÁvila pero porque complicarse si es simple, todo depende de como quieras mantener los controles. Si es solo uno usa el Clear() y luego asigna la instancia. Si quieres mantener varios alli recomendaria usar Tabs para mostrar cada user control en una tabpage distinto

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que cuando agregas un Control a la colección `controls` de cada container el *z-order* se actualiza y este se envía al fondo. Lo bueno es que tienes disponible métodos para modificar esto.

Tienes este método disponible al heredar de Control:

```
Control.BringToFront()
```

Por ejemplo:

```
 panel1.BringToFront();
```

También puedes manejar el *z-order* de cada control dentro de la colección `Controls` de cada `container` con `GetChildIndex` y `SetChildIndex`

```
// Obtener el  index de un control
int zIndex = controlPadre.Controls.GetChildIndex(textBox);
// Enviar al frente
textBox.BringToFront();
// aqui tu programa hace algo ...
// Luego lo mandamos donde estaba antes de traerlo al frente
controlPadre.Controls.SetChildIndex(textBox, zIndex);
```